# AlertDialog: contextual ActionBar appears behind status-bar

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, contextual-action-bar, android-appcompat

Long pressing an EditText added to an AlertDialog should normally show a contextual ActionBar, but when using AppCompat the contextual ActionBar appears behind the status-bar. The contextual ActionBar is also not clickable.

The same behavior can be seen when showing an AlertDialog directly from an Activity.

**Android versions tested:** 4.4, 5.0, 5.1
**AppCompat version:** 22.1.1 and 22.1.0

**Source code (Gradle Module):** [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bysh00fNuF86QmRHSTdMdEVNQ3M/view?usp=sharing)

I tried adding `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` but this does not fix the problem.

What can I do the make the contextual ActionBar appear normal?

[image: ActionMode shown behind status-bar]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText customView = new EditText(this);
        customView.setText("Select me");

        AlertDialog.Builder test = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        test.setView(customView);
        test.setPositiveButton("Close", null);
        test.setTitle("ActionMode test");
        test.show();
    }
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Test.AlertDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Test.AlertDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <!-- Removing android:windowFullscreen yields same result -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What if you do not edit the `alertDialogTheme`?

Comment: Same result ;) I initially did not even touch the theme.

Comment: What is in your layout? is this a new project?

Comment: Completely new project, see download for the full source. The Activity layout is just a RelativeLayout with a Button nothing more.

Comment: Unless it is on Github and easy to view, I do not feel comfortable downloading files. This is strange and new. You might be able to submit a bug for this.

Comment: I was thinking the same about reporting this as bug. I will include the full source in this post as soon as I have access to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

As he said he would, Rolf created [AOSP Issue 170658](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170658).  That issue was closed as a duplicate of [170105](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170105). Issue 170105 indicates the problem has been fixed internally and will appear in a future release of the AppCompat library.  No indication of when that release might occur.